# why do we need filebeat when we can ship logs to Logstatsh

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Hi as a newbie to elastic I have a doubt on why we need fileBeat to ship logs to ElasticSearch(ES) or Logstatsh.

As far as I knew we can directly read logs from files and send to logstash and from there to ES. If the former is allowed why we need FileBeat to be a intermediary layer between logs and logstash.

What i knew : `xyzlogfile--->logstash-file--->ES--->kibana`
Why do we need FileBeat between : `xyzlogfile--->fileBeat--->logstash-file--->ES--->kibana`

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are talking about File Input Plugin vs Filebeat.

Some points to note:

1. Logstash is much heavier in terms of memory and CPU usage than Filebeat. It requires a JVM which might be fine if you deploy java software but for many projects a JVM is an unnecessary overhead. Filebeat is just a light native executable.
2. You might not need Logstash at all

- If your logs are JSON
- If you don't need any parsing and you are ok with timestamps generated by Filebeat (**[EDIT 2021-01-01]** Filebeat has various processors, it can even do arbitrary script execution, pure go implementation of ECMASCRIPT 5.1, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/processor-script.html)
- If you have simple regex parsing (e.g. grok filter) you can just use Ingest Nodes (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/ingest.html)

1. For more complex parsing/event cloning/grouping Logstash will probably be needed. Just writing a ruby filter for example is super easy and you can prototype fast. For optimizing super high production loads you might need to write a custom filter plugin, or perhaps you can try writing your own custom Processor to be used with Ingest Nodes (but I haven't tried that yet, I can tell you that writing a custom Logstash filter is pretty straightforward)
2. All the above points are related to ingesting file contents, but Logstash has many input/output plugins that you might need and are only available with Logstash

If all your files are located on the same node as the logstash process, than using the File Input Plugin could be an option ("xyzlogfile--->logstash-file--->ES--->kibana").

However for most deployments you want to collect data from many nodes with different roles and software stacks deployed on them. You do not want to deploy a Logstash instance on all those nodes, so "xyzlogfile--->fileBeat--->logstash-beats--->ES--->kibana" should be used (or another option is "xyzlogfile--->fileBeat--->ES--->kibana" with Ingest Node).

Answer (score 1):

Based On **Mastering Elastic Stack** by Packt:

Beats are **data shippers**  shipping data from a variety of inputs such as files, data streams, or logs whereas Logstash is a **data parser**. Though Logstash can ship data, it's not its primary usage.

Logstash **consumes a lot of memory and requires a higher amount of resources** , whereas Beats **requires fewer resources and consumes low memory**.